# Default nested structure initialization

Tags: c++, syntax, initialization

Is there a syntax to initialize DataItem dh.size element to sizeof(DataItem)? The code below uses constructor and relying on compiler to optimize things to constant values. Not the perfect solution... Is there a syntax to initialize nested structs?

```
struct DataHeader_t {
    int sz = 0;
    int type = 0;
};

struct DataItem {
    DataItem() {dh.sz = sizeof(DataItem);}
    DataHeader_t dh;
    float data1 = 0;
    float data2 = 0;
    ...
};
```

Comment: `int sz = sizeof *this`?

Comment: What's wrong with initializing things in a construtor? It's only a matter of style anyway.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In worst case initialization will be done in runtime, but it can be done in compile time

Comment: Give `DataHeader_t` a `constexpr` c'tor. Call that from your own classes c'tor, and hope you've given the compiler enough clues.

Comment: @user657267 won't work, because it's not `this`, it's the size of the struct containing the struct. also, `this` might not even be defined at that point (might be UB, not sure), because there's no instance here.

Comment: It depends on compiler optimizations, not on a syntax you're using. When you assign values to fields inside of a class definition, you just implicitly add these assignments to all construtors. There is no real difference other than code style.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's fine for [`this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) to appear in a default member initializer, I didn't notice that OP wanted the `sizeof` the parent class though.

Comment: @user657267 pretty sure OP wants the sizeof the struct containing the `DataHeader_t` struct. It's a common mechanism to have polymorphism in C. (the question, of course would be why he does it in C++)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well yes, I agree, that's what I said

Comment: @user657267 ah, sorry, I misread.

Comment: @MarcusMüller can you propose c++ way of doing such nested initialization in compile time?

Comment: @tohaz: no. Read my answer.

Comment: Why are so concerned with this happening at compile time, anyways? What's your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not the perfect solution... Is there a syntax to initialize nested structs?

Yes, that structure is called constructor, and you're already using it.

Comment: "The code below uses constructor and relying on compiler to optimize things to constant values"

Comment: @tohaz: exactly, that's what I'm saying, and what I was referring to. To make this clearer: No, there's no better way, because c'tors are the *right* and *only* way.